# How to get analytical solution for integral from product of Bessel functions with integer orders

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

The following integral appears to be problematic for me:

$\int_a^b r J_s(k r) Y_d(k r) \, dr$

The result returned by Mathematica in response to the next input

```
$Assumptions = 
  a ∈ Reals && b ∈ Reals && k ∈ Reals && 
   r ∈ Reals && b > a && a > 0 && b > 0 && k > 0 && r > 0 && 
   s ∈ Integers && d ∈ Integers;
Integrate[r*BesselJ[s, k*r]*BesselY[d, k*r], r]
```

contains $\csc (\pi  d)$ and $\cot (\pi  d)$, both of which correspond to `ComplexInfinity` in case of integer order `d`.

It appeared to be possible to integrate the expression for specific values of Bessel function orders. This can be used for determining dependence of coefficient values in integration results upon orders `s` and `d`. Also, there are certain values of `s` and `d` for which analytic result doesn't coincide with the result of numeric integration (for example s=3,d=7). Because of that the range of orders for which I obtained a solution is limited to $\left| s\right| \geq \left| d\right|$. I need help with a solution for remaining part of the domain.

I was not able to find this integral in table of integrals by Gradshtein & Ryzhik. Maple left this integral unevaluated.

Tried Integrate`InverseIntegrate and Rubi with no success.

Comment: Is there a reason why you think this integral has an analytical solution? Also it seems you can "eliminate" $k$ by a change of variable.

Comment: @anderstood, it does have one, but OP's problem is that the solution returned by *Mathematica* is no good for integer $d$, but fine otherwise (yet another instance of "generically correct").

Comment: @J.M. Oh I see. Interestingly, with `f[r_, d_, s_, k_] = Integrate[r*BesselJ[s, k*r]*BesselY[d, k*r], r]`, the plot `Plot[f[3.2, d, 3.6, 1], {d, 0, 10}]` seems "fine" for integer values of `d`. Maybe the solution is always correct, but its evaluation is only generically correct.

Comment: @anderstood, Concerning the question: "Is there a reason why you think this integral has an analytical solution?". How can I answer it? Do you mean there is kind of theorem that can prove existence of analytic solution?          The solution is not even close to "fine" because in my case s is integer too. Try plotting `Plot[f[3.2, d, 2, 1], {d, 0, 10}]`.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for $\left| s\right| \geq \left| d\right|$ have already been derived as stated in question. It has the following form

```
Tas901=(1/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]]))(-a^2 MeijerG[{{0,1/2 Mod[d+s,2]},{1/2 Boole[Mod[d+s,2]==0]}},{{1/2 (Abs[d]+Abs[s]),1/2 Abs[Abs[d]-Abs[s]]},{-1,1/2 (-Abs[d]-Abs[s]),-(1/2) Abs[Abs[d]-Abs[s]]}},a k,1/2]+b^2 MeijerG[{{0,1/2 Mod[d+s,2]},{1/2 Boole[Mod[d+s,2]==0]}},{{1/2 (Abs[d]+Abs[s]),1/2 Abs[Abs[d]-Abs[s]]},{-1,1/2 (-Abs[d]-Abs[s]),-(1/2) Abs[Abs[d]-Abs[s]]}},b k,1/2]) (\[Piecewise]  -1  Mod[d+3 s,4]<=1
1   True

)
```

Using the relation from http://functions.wolfram.com/03.03.26.0026.01

$Y_{\mu }\left(\sqrt{z}\right) J_{\nu }\left(\sqrt{z}\right)+J_{\mu }\left(\sqrt{z}\right) Y_{\nu }\left(\sqrt{z}\right)=-\frac{2 G_{2,4}^{3,0}\left(z\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 0,\frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{\mu -\nu }{2},\frac{\nu -\mu }{2},\frac{\mu +\nu }{2},\frac{1}{2} (-\mu -\nu ) \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}$

we can swap the orders of Bessel functions. Let us apply this rule to the integrand:

```
Expand[r*BesselJ[s, k*r]*BesselY[d, k*r] /. 
  HoldPattern[
    BesselJ[\[Nu]_, z_]*BesselY[\[Mu]_, z_]] :> -((
     2 MeijerG[{{}, {0, 1/2}}, {{(\[Mu] + \[Nu])/2, (\[Mu] - \[Nu])/
         2, (\[Nu] - \[Mu])/2}, {-(1/2) (\[Mu] + \[Nu])}}, z^2])/
     Sqrt[\[Pi]]) - BesselJ[\[Mu], z]*BesselY[\[Nu], z]]
```

As a result we obtain two summands, which need to be integrated

```
-r BesselJ[d, k r] BesselY[s, k r] - (
 2 r MeijerG[{{}, {0, 1/2}}, {{(d - s)/2, 1/2 (-d + s), (d + s)/
     2}, {1/2 (-d - s)}}, k^2 r^2])/Sqrt[\[Pi]]
```

The first one is already solved. Fortunately, the second summand can be integrated by Mathematica without any problems.

```
 tmp = Integrate[-((
   2 r MeijerG[{{}, {0, 1/2}}, {{(d - s)/2, 1/2 (-d + s), (d + s)/
       2}, {1/2 (-d - s)}}, k^2 r^2])/Sqrt[\[Pi]]), r]


(* -(MeijerG[{{1}, {1, 3/2}}, {{1/2 (2 + d - s), 1/2 (2 - d + s), 
        1/2 (2 + d + s)}, {0, 1/2 (2 - d - s)}}, k^2 r^2]/(
     k^2 Sqrt[\[Pi]])) *)
```

Then we use the solution for $\left| s\right| \geq \left| d\right|$ for derivation of solution for $\left| s\right| <\left| d\right|$ (expression correspond to above expanded integrand):

```
Tas902 = (((-Tas901 /. s -> sTemp) /. d -> s) /. 
    sTemp -> d) + ((tmp /. r -> b) - (tmp /. r -> a))
```

Gathering integration results for two pieces of domain

```
Tas9= 
 Piecewise[{{Tas901, Abs[s] >= Abs[d]}, {Tas902, 
    Abs[s] < Abs[d]}}]
```

we can express the solution to the integral in question as follows:

```
\[Piecewise]    (1/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]]))(-a^2 MeijerG[{{0,1/2 Mod[d+s,2]},{1/2 Boole[Mod[d+s,2]==0]}},{{1/2 (Abs[d]+Abs[s]),1/2 Abs[Abs[d]-Abs[s]]},{-1,1/2 (-Abs[d]-Abs[s]),-(1/2) Abs[Abs[d]-Abs[s]]}},a k,1/2]+b^2 MeijerG[{{0,1/2 Mod[d+s,2]},{1/2 Boole[Mod[d+s,2]==0]}},{{1/2 (Abs[d]+Abs[s]),1/2 Abs[Abs[d]-Abs[s]]},{-1,1/2 (-Abs[d]-Abs[s]),-(1/2) Abs[Abs[d]-Abs[s]]}},b k,1/2]) (\[Piecewise] -1  Mod[d+3 s,4]<=1
1   True

)   Abs[s]>=Abs[d]
(1/(2 k^2 Sqrt[\[Pi]]))(2 MeijerG[{{1},{1,3/2}},{{1/2 (2+d-s),1/2 (2-d+s),1/2 (2+d+s)},{0,1/2 (2-d-s)}},a^2 k^2]-2 MeijerG[{{1},{1,3/2}},{{1/2 (2+d-s),1/2 (2-d+s),1/2 (2+d+s)},{0,1/2 (2-d-s)}},b^2 k^2]+k^2 (a^2 MeijerG[{{0,1/2 Mod[d+s,2]},{1/2 Boole[Mod[d+s,2]==0]}},{{1/2 (Abs[d]+Abs[s]),1/2 Abs[Abs[d]-Abs[s]]},{-1,1/2 (-Abs[d]-Abs[s]),-(1/2) Abs[Abs[d]-Abs[s]]}},a k,1/2]-b^2 MeijerG[{{0,1/2 Mod[d+s,2]},{1/2 Boole[Mod[d+s,2]==0]}},{{1/2 (Abs[d]+Abs[s]),1/2 Abs[Abs[d]-Abs[s]]},{-1,1/2 (-Abs[d]-Abs[s]),-(1/2) Abs[Abs[d]-Abs[s]]}},b k,1/2]) (\[Piecewise]   -1  Mod[3 d+s,4]<=1
1   True

))  Abs[s]<Abs[d]
0   True
```

Comparison with numeric integration can be done for the equal precisions of computation results

```
Grid[Prepend[
  Table[Flatten@{"d=" <> ToString@id, 
     Table[ruleSet = {s -> is, d -> id, k -> 1/7, a -> 1/8, b -> 1/4};
       N[Tas9[s, d] /. ruleSet, 8] == 
       NIntegrate[r*BesselJ[s, k*r]*BesselY[d, k*r] /. ruleSet, 
        Evaluate[{r, a, b} /. ruleSet], PrecisionGoal -> 8], {is, -4, 
       4}]}, {id, -5, 5}], Flatten@{"s=", Range[-4, 4]}], 
 Frame -> All, Background -> {{{White, Pink}}, {{Cyan, Yellow}}}]
```

The result of comparison
$\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 \text{s=} & -4 & -3 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 \text{d=-5} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} \\
 \text{d=-4} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} \\
 \text{d=-3} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} \\
 \text{d=-2} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} \\
 \text{d=-1} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} \\
 \text{d=0} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} \\
 \text{d=1} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} \\
 \text{d=2} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} \\
 \text{d=3} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} \\
 \text{d=4} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} \\
 \text{d=5} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} & \text{True} \\
\end{array}$

shows that solution is valid for any integer orders `s` and `d`.

Concluding the above stated, I have to avow, that the solution procedure is irrational and was found by the merest chance. A more systematic approach to solution of integrals with integer orders of Bessel functions is still required.